# Java Generics - Copy values from sibling class

Tags: java, reflection

Is possible to do this in Java?

```
public class serviceClass<T extends BaseClass, D extends BaseClass> {

    private T copyPropertiesValues(D item) {

        BaseClass item2 =  item.getClass().getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(item, item2);

        T newItem = (T) item2;

        //newItem is an instance of D instead of T

    }

}
```

The only way that I found to do this is by going to the "T" class and creating a constructor that takes "D" as parameter.

But I will create a lot of other classes that inherits from BaseClass, and I will need to do this one by one, "repeating" the code.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

Adding more details:

BaseClass.java

```
@Data
public abstract class BaseClass {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String integrationStatus;
}
```

ParentClass.java (represents the different fields from different tables, but contains "id" and "integrationStatus") - **There will be a lot of this type in my project**

```
@Data
public abstract class ParentClass extends BaseClass {

    private String col001;
    private String col002;
    ///other fields
}
```

ChildClass (Represents "T" and "D") - **There will be only two for each ParentClass**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(schema = "DB_[number]", table="sameTable")
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    
    public ChildClass() {}

    public ChildClass(ParentClass otherObj) {
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(otherObj, this)
    }

}
```

Comment: @Slaw The only difference between T an D it is the @Table(schema) annotation. The only way that I managed to do is by creating a constructor on both T and D which receives the opposite class as parameter.

Comment: When they have the exact same properties, then why don't they store those in the parent class?

Comment: @Tom The T and D parent class inherits from BaseClass. The parent class contains the properties which are used by T and D. But I can't change the "extends from BaseClass" to "extends from ParentClass" because ParentClass will change.

Comment: I don't quite follow why you would need to do this but instead of T and D could you implement a common interface  V and use that as an inter-instance vehicle for passing specific values?  Or even a common Map which can hold values understood by multiple classes.  The casting of said values could be problematic.

Comment: You can not create a constructor in `T`. `T` is a type variable, not a class. The actual class can be whatever the caller likes to use. Even if that particular class had a constructor, the `copyPropertiesValues` method doesn’t know what class has been used for `T`. There’s not even a guaranty that the actual type argument is a class that can be instantiated. So you are asking the wrong question.